# Como verificar se uma string está contida em outra?

Tags: java, string

Tenho diversas strings em uma `ArrayList`. Gostaria de saber como retornar uma string dessa lista que contenha outra que foi passada. Por exemplo, se eu passar uma `String` `"Bean"`, quero retornar a string `"AtendenteBean"`.

Comment: Cara, continua muito confuso. O que exatamente pode vir nesta `String` `Bean`? Que tipo de código você espera como resposta? Qual é o formato deste `xhtml`? Além de `AtendenteBean`, o que mais esta `String` poderia ser? Você tem uma classe `AtendenteBean`? Se sim, como é esta classe?

Comment: Cara, quero o seguinte, vou passar um parte de uma `String`, `Bean` por exemplo, e me retorna `AtendenteBean`. Eu extraio o texto de dentro da página `xhtml`. Seria como por exemplo uma busca em `sql` usando like`.

Comment: `Eu extraio o texto de dentro da página xhtml`, extrai e armazena onde no seu código? Um vetor, um ArrayList? Talvez voce devesse deixar essa parte de xhtml de lado na sua pergunta, ja que essa informacao não parece relevante para alguma pessoa dar a resposta que voce precisa

Comment: @Math eu armazeno em uma estrutura com `ArrayList`

Comment: Olha, a classe String tem o método **contains()**. Até onde entendi é isso que você quer...http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: Tá, vai ficar muito grande mas tudo bem. Imaginem que isso é uma `String`. `Este texto contem algumas palavras de dúvida de alguém que queira saber pelos usuários do stackOverflow como resolver sua dúvida`. E ai, eu quero por exemplo passar a `String` vida, e me retorna a palavra `dúvida`. Entenderam?

Answer (score 5):

Considerando que você está usando um `ArrayList` para armazenar suas `String`s eu aconselharia você a percorrer todas as variáveis da sua lista e verificar se ela contém o texto desejado. Exemplo:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

//pega os dados do xhtml e joga na variavel list

for(String s: list) {
    if(s.contains("Bean")) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima estou imprimindo todos as `String`s que possuem o literal `Bean` da variável `list` e depois imprimindo ele. Ao invés de imprimir você pode manipular a variável `s` do jeito que desejar, ela contém o trecho do literal que você pôs no condicional `if` acima.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você está confundindo o que é uma "String". Você não quer dizer uma classe AtendenteBean, que por exemplo herda de PessoaBean? Se você tem certeza de que uma instância de PessoaBean é uma AtendenteBean, você pode usar um cast, veja se o exemplo abaixo faz sentido:

```
PessoaBean p = findPessoa(...);
if (p instanceof AtendenteBean) }
    String codAtendente = ((AtendenteBean) p).getCodAtendente();
}
```

Comment: eu não estou confundindo, apenas quero pegar um texto que esta dentro de uma pagina, passando uma parte deste texto.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui utilizando `regex`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(.+?)Bean");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()){
    beanName = matcher.group(1);
    beanName = beanName.concat("Bean");

    if (text.contains(beanName)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Ele procura por palavras que contem `Bean` e iniciam com a chave `{`. Caso o texto contenham, ele quebra o loop.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, tente elaborar melhor a sua pergunta, não consegui entender exatamente o que você quis dizer.

De qualquer forma, me parece que o que você quer seja algo do tipo `objeto.getClass().getSimpleName()`.

Comment: realmente faltou eu colocar que `Bean` é uma parte de uma String